React native bundle size
I am working on my react native project, with new bridgeless architecture, when making a release build the version size is 60mb knowing not that third party libraries
Trying to get a lower bundle size 20 mb and getting 60 mb

In your source folder navigate to android/app/build.gradle and add the following lines
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
Proguard optimizes and shrinks down your Java bytecode, thereby reducing app size.
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
There are several CPU architectures that Android supports (armebi and x86 for example). By creating separate builds for each, we are able to cut down on app size. As we are using App Bundle, we don’t have to handle the separate APKs and Google will do the heavy lifting for us.
